# c# validation automation in data anontations

Tags: c#, validation, automation, data-annotations

Summary: Im working with C# 4.5 version and more specifically in Web API.

Im trying to build an object and wrap it with attributes so when I receive a HTTP POST request, validation will be made in modelState.

a little example before code:

Lets say I have this following request object

```
public class PlayerRequest
{
    [TeamId]
    public string TeamId {set;get;}

    [UserId]
    public string UserId {set;get;}
}
```

now, I want to be able to just add an attribute to the class and it will check if class contains `TeamId` and `UserId` and if so, validate in db that in fact user has access to team.
so lets say, the declaration will be something like:

```
[PairsValidate]
public class TeamRequest
{
     //...
}
```

What I aim to create is not a specific validation for `TeamId` and `UserId` but to create some sort of a pool of attribute pairs and run a simple loop to detect them and validate.

code so far:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public sealed class AccessValidator : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly AttributePairValidator[] _validators = 
        {
            UserIdTeamIdValidator.GetInstance(AccessManager.UserAccessToTeam)
        };

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = value.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
            {
                foreach (AttributePairValidator valPair in _validators)
                {
                    valPair.Accept(/* here is the problem */ , p.GetValue as string);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class AttributePairValidator
    {
        protected string fieldA;
        protected string fieldB;
        protected Func<string, string, Task<bool>> _validationMethod;
        protected static object _lockObj = new object();

        protected AttributePairValidator(Func<string, string, Task<bool>> validationMethod)
        {
            _validationMethod = validationMethod;
        }

        public bool Accept (ValidationAttribute attr, string val)
        {
            return true;
        }

        protected async Task<bool> Check()
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldA) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldB))
                return await _validationMethod(fieldA, fieldB);

            return true;
        }
    }

    public sealed class UserIdTeamIdValidator : AttributePairValidator
    {
        private static UserIdTeamIdValidator _instance = null;

        private UserIdTeamIdValidator(Func<string, string, Task<bool>> validationMethod) : base (validationMethod)
        {

        }

        public static UserIdTeamIdValidator GetInstance(Func<string, string, Task<bool>> validationMethod)
        {
            lock (_lockObj)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                    _instance = new UserIdTeamIdValidator(validationMethod);
            }
            return _instance;
        }

        public async Task<bool> Accept(UserIdAttribute attr, string val)
        {
            fieldA = val;
            return await Check();
        }

        public async Task<bool> Accept(TeamIdAttribute attr, string val)
        {
            fieldB = val;
            return await Check();
        }
    }
```

other issue, if you guys already know how to solve it.
Im validating the request itself by headers and im storing some data in the actionContext's principal. In controllers i use: `ActionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name`
is there any way to get this data when in validationAttribute scope?

Thanks.